# Footer within content frame

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Footer is sitting within the website frame rather than beneath it:

http://www.lauradawaf.co.uk/contact

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inner">
    <span>Laura Dawaf &copy; | +44(0)7979 427 527 | <a href="mailto:info@lauradawaf.co.uk">info@lauradawaf.co.uk</a </span>
                    </div>

<a href="#top">Back to top.</a>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    margin:0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin:54px 0 0 0;
    color: #9E9D9D;
}
```

and the footer isn't visible on the portfolio page:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOW SOME change in your css style seet as like this

Only three changing in your layout coding than your desing is perfect demo is below

```
#project_thumbnails.isotope{
overflow:hidden;  // remove this line in your inline stylesheet
}


#primary.isotope-item{
position:abslute; // remove this line in your inline stylesheet
}

#footer.isotope-item{
position:absolute; // remove this line in your inline stylesheet 
}
```

[image]

**If you now find this css in your html page than apply in your main css styesheet as like this**

```
#project_thumbnails.isotope{
    overflow: auto !important;  // add this css in your main css file
    }


    #primary.isotope-item{
    position:static  !important; //add this css in your main css file
    }

    #footer.isotope-item{
    position:static !important; // add this css in your main css file
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find the inline stylesheet in Wordpress?

Comment: @sorry but i have no idea in wordpress but you can add this css in your stylesheet with !important overwrite as like this #primary.isotope-item{
position:static !important; }                                                  #footer.isotope-item{
position:static !important;  
}                  #project_thumbnails.isotope{
overflow:auto !important;
}

Comment: Thank you although it seems to have put a scroll bar on the skills page!

Answer (score 0):

Remove position absolute from div#primary and div#footer.